# React Native - Android - How to convert activity to transparent?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to convert React native android activity to transparent, however, I am only able to achieve translucent behavior with the below code.

So how can I make the activity as completely transparent instead of translucent?

**RNActivity.kt**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        RnUtils.convertActivityToTranslucent(this)
        setTheme(R.style.ThemeTransparent)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mReactRootView?.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyApp", intent.extras)
        setContentView(mReactRootView)
    }
```

**RnUtils.kt**

```
public static void convertActivityToTranslucent(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            convertActivityToTranslucentAfterL(activity);
        } else {
            convertActivityToTranslucentBeforeL(activity);
        }
    }

    private static void convertActivityToTranslucentBeforeL(Activity activity) {
        try {
            Class<?>[] classes = Activity.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Class<?> translucentConversionListenerClazz = null;
            for (Class clazz : classes) {
                if (clazz.getSimpleName().contains("TranslucentConversionListener")) {
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz = clazz;
                }
            }
            Method method = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToTranslucent",
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(activity, new Object[]{
                    null
            });
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
    }

    private static void convertActivityToTranslucentAfterL(Activity activity) {
        try {
            Method getActivityOptions = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("getActivityOptions");
            getActivityOptions.setAccessible(true);
            Object options = getActivityOptions.invoke(activity);

            Class<?>[] classes = Activity.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Class<?> translucentConversionListenerClazz = null;
            for (Class clazz : classes) {
                if (clazz.getSimpleName().contains("TranslucentConversionListener")) {
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz = clazz;
                }
            }
            Method convertToTranslucent = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToTranslucent",
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz, ActivityOptions.class);
            convertToTranslucent.setAccessible(true);
            convertToTranslucent.invoke(activity, null, options);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
    }
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ThemeTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use color that Hex format or RGBA format, RGBA(0,0,0,0) or #00000000
here example for react native. [source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props)

```
<View style={styles.activity}>
  
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activity: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)"
  }
});
```